# Encoding and decoding get parameters in CodeIgniter not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption, getparameter

I would like to encrypt and decrypt the get parameters in [CodeIgniter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeigniter#CodeIgniter).

I have written the following code:

```
 <a href="<?php echo site_url('package?product='.$this->encrypt->encode('database').
  '&price='.$this->encrypt->encode('5000')); ?>">BUY NOW</a>
```

For testing, this in my package.php view in which I have written the following:

```
 echo $this->encrypt->decode($_GET['product']);
 echo "<br/>";
 echo $this->encrypt->decode($_GET['price']);
```

But when I click on the link, sometimes it shows both values, sometimes only one of the values and sometimes nothing...

Comment: try to explain your encrypt/decrypt code

Comment: your key might be encoding with `&` and `?` or any other variables which can create issues

Comment: i have used the default CI encryption class... any suggestion..to this in any other way but with CI only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solves my problem:

#### Update

Just create the below class in your library folder and name the file `Encryption` then you can load it in our `autoload.php` or directly in your controller. See an example:

```
$this->load->library('encryption'); //in controller
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','encryption'); // In autoload.php
```

---

The Encryption class:

```
class Encryption {

    var $skey = "MUHAMMAD";

    public function safe_b64encode($string) {

        $data = base64_encode($string);
        $data = str_replace(array('+', '/', '='), array('-', '_', ''), $data);
        return $data;
    }

    public function safe_b64decode($string) {
        $data = str_replace(array('-', '_'), array('+', '/'), $string);
        $mod4 = strlen($data) % 4;
        if ($mod4) {
            $data .= substr('====', $mod4);
        }
        return base64_decode($data);
    }

    public function encode($value) {

        if (!$value) {
            return false;
        }
        $text = $value;
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->skey, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
        return trim($this->safe_b64encode($crypttext));
    }

    public function decode($value) {

        if (!$value) {
            return false;
        }
        $crypttext = $this->safe_b64decode($value);
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $decrypttext = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->skey, $crypttext, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
        return trim($decrypttext);
    }

}
```

And to use the library class after loading it, see below:

```
$encrypt = $this->encryption->encode('Anything...');
$decrypt = $this->encryption->decode($encrypt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to check this configuration, inside `application/config/config.php`

`$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';`

Maybe the decode is trying to pass some char that is not inside permitted_uri_chars